# How to use base64 string in Google pass event ticket logo

Tags: android-pay, google-pay

I am using Google Passes API and creating Passes using C#. I want to use base64 string for event ticket logo but not getting any option for that. Is there any possibility that we can use base64 string for event ticket logo

payload.Logo = new Image();

payload.Logo.SourceUri = new ImageUri();

payload.Logo.SourceUri.Uri = "HTTP://www.example.com/test.jpg";

Comment: I've to create Google Passes using C#, may you guide me on it or can share any link so that I can go to step by step? It will be highly appreciable if you can help me on it

Comment: https://github.com/google-pay/passes-rest-samples/tree/master/csharp This is the github Url I followed. Apart from that you can follow https://developers.google.com/pay/passes/guides/introduction/about-google-pay-api-for-passes

Comment: Thnx lots @Shailendra

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No option to do this, [must be URI](https://developers.google.com/pay/passes/rest/v1/Image#ImageUri):

{
"uri": string,
"description": string,
"localizedDescription": {
object (LocalizedString)
}
}